# SOAP client "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, soap, ssl

A bit of background I am developing a webpage that connects to a web service using SOAP.
I get this error when I am call a method on the web service:

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

Now here is where it gets weird, it only happens when I run the website under IIS. Running under the visual studio development server everything works as expected.

I have been reading around and have found similar problems. First I ruled out the certificate that is being used to authenticate with the server. After getting the certificate from X509Store I used the GetRawCertDataString() method to write the certificate data to a file and running under IIS and VS they are identical.

I have also tried:

```
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

with no luck.

I then enabled SChannel logging.
Running under VS I can see the information messages with the handshake being successful under VS:

```
An SSL client handshake completed successfully. The negotiated cryptographic parameters are as follows.

   Protocol: SSL 3.0
   CipherSuite: 0xa
   Exchange strength: 2048
```

But there are no error messages when it is running under IIS. There is the information message  when the private key data is sent, then nothing.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks